# Usage of ずつ片す in this sentence

Tags: readings, reading-comprehension

> 7時半

> 各方面に連絡も済ませたし

> 見積書も作り直した

> あとは返事来たやつから1個ずつ片すだけ

Context: an office worker just finished setting his business and it's early in the morning, after he pulled an all-nighter. This dialog is all said by the same person, reflecting on his current progresses.

I understand the fist sentence are like "I finished contacting everyone and the written estimates have been redone"

however, I'm unsure on how to interpreter the last sentence.

"The people who replied"

個ずつ片すだけ  "One by one"? I'll strike them out?

Answer (score 1):

The やつ here is not a person but *one (thing)*. 返事が来たやつ means *the ones that were replied to*. From the provided text, more concretely it refers to 連絡 (or matters that 連絡 is about).

[かたす](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%99/#jn-41877) means 片づける=to sort out. Strike out is a derived meaning from *to get (something) done/do away with*.

So overall, it is something like *Now, out of the ones that got replied to, I will proceed one by one.*.

Comment: "got replied / was replied" sounds weird. In everyday use "got replied **to** / was replied **to**" would be better. Although I think strict grammarians would moan about that too. A safer phrase would be "the ones where I got a reply".

Comment: @user3856370 Oh, [I see](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7178/reply-him-or-reply-to-him). Actually never thought about it. Fixed, leaving the passive for the literal translation.

Comment: To be clear he's saying he will "sort out the names" of those who have called? And not strike out?

Comment: @Kawase_K I thought you meant something like *knock down* by strike out. Anyway, it has nothing to do with names. かたす is just working on/finishing the job. Any reply will create a job for the speaker and s/he is saying that s/he will just handle it one by one as replies come. I just can't tell what the job is about from the provided text.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that やつ could not possibly refer to a person. It is true that you would never use that term to a person's face as it would be extremely offensive, but this is presumably inner thoughts not being spoken out loud. やつ certainly can refer to things, and is as malleable or even moreso than the English word "thing" (or "stuff").

But here's my personal interpretation:

> "Seven-thirty."
>  "I finished sending out the emails everywhere to
> everyone, check."
>  "I revised the estimates."
>  "Now all that's
> left is dealing with the replies from the clients one by one."

I'm obviously only guessing here that he's referring to clients and that the mode of communication was email, but the やつ I believe points to them (the clients).

As a last remark, ずつ片す aren't together as one word, it is 1個ずつ "one by one" and after that comes 片す which is a shortened 片づける, "clean up," "tidy up," or "process/deal with."